# set base URL dynamicaly in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two versions of a site one running at on example.com
and other at example.com/version2.

In web.php I have

```
    Route::group(['middleware'=>['webconfig'],'prefix'=>'version2'], function(){
        //Routes for version2 site
    });
// Routes for main site
```

In webconfig middleware I set database connection for version2 site. Which is working fine but I am also setting base URL for version2 site. which not working `url()` method returns example.com
Here is my webconfig middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    \Config::set('database.default', 'mysql_us');
    \Config::set('app.url', url('version2'));
    return $next($request);
}
```

So how can I set base url dynamicaly.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the URL, otherwise the group would change `version2` to `version2/version2`, and may get stuck in a loop.

Comment: `app.url` is used by the console, not for web requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .env file specify APP_URL=http://example.com/version2

Comment: I want to  change app URL dynamically ie programaticaly

Comment: You may need to run "php artisan config:cache" too

Answer (score 2):

since your 2 version deployed in the same hosting and you just add a prefix '`version2`' for your new version. why not just create a middleware that checked your segment(1) if it's version2 or not then set the correct database that it'll be using. I believe you want to redirect to other database when users are in `version2` segment, am i right?

In this case you can just use a solution like this in your middleware,

```
if (Str::lower($request->segment(1) == "version2") {
    config()->set('database.default', 'mysql_us');
} else {
    // your another config.
}
```

i hope this will help you with your issue.